# How to auto trigger email functionality after running test suite from testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have created a test suite from testng.xml and want to auto trigger an email with the emailable-report.xml. I have written the code to trigger the email and while running that code,I am able to send the email. However after running the suite putting that email code in @AfterSuite, the email is not getting triggered.

Can someone help me with this, what I need to do to make that thing work?

Code to send email:

```
package ServiceUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class EMailClass{

    public static Properties Config = new Properties();


    @AfterSuite
    public static void SendEmail() throws IOException
    {           
                String abspath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
                String ConfigFileLocation = abspath + "/src/main/java/testProperties/Config.properties";
                FileInputStream LoadFile = new FileInputStream(ConfigFileLocation);
                Config.load(LoadFile);
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.getProperty("SenderEmailAddress"), Config.getProperty("SenderEmailPassword"));
                            }
                        });
                try {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                //  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(Config.getProperty("ReceiverEmailAddress")));
                    message.setSubject(Config.getProperty("EmailSubject"));
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart1.setText(Config.getProperty("EmailBody"));
                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    String filename = Config.getProperty("EmailFiletoAttach1");
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                    messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
                    message.setContent(multipart);
                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");

                } catch (MessagingException e) {

                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                }


    }
}
```

Sample Testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Regression Suite 1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Regression suite 1" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.automation.cc"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include `EMailClass` in the suite then TestNG is not able to know it. Try with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Regression Suite 1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Regression suite 1" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.automation.cc"/>
      <class name="ServiceUtils.EMailClass"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Or you can do:

```
public class cc extends EMailClass {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked this way, however will it not work if we put this code in @Aftertest or @AfterSuite?

Comment: It should work with `@Aftertest` and `@AfterSuite` too

Comment: I am experiencing two issues. Pls help. 1) After doing what u said (i.e, including the email class in testng.xml) the report (emailable report ) which it is sending is of the previous run instead of the current run. 2) When I put this in @Aftersuite/@Aftertest it didn't worked as mentioned in my initial question. Pls help regarding this